# How to randomly assign color to verts individually inside a "for loop" but not to the whole mesh?

Tags: python, maya

I have a piece of code which is supposed to grab all verts of an object and then through the use of "for loop" assign them a random color value inside a grayscale range.

The following code selects every vert of the mesh one by one but does not assign a color to each one of them. Instead it assigns a color to all of them at the same time filling the whole object with a uniform color.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import functools
import random

colorList =cmds.ls('colorSet*' )
sphereList = cmds.ls( 'mySphere*' )
if len( sphereList ) > 0:
    cmds.delete( sphereList)

result = cmds.polySphere ( r=50, sx=random.randrange(10, 100), sy=random.randrange(10,100), name='mySphere#' )


cmds.polyColorSet ( create=True, colorSet='colorSet1')

def get_random_vertexes():
        percent = 1
        vertexes = []
        for obj in cmds.ls(sl=1, long=1):
            indexes = range(cmds.polyEvaluate(obj, vertex=1))
            random.shuffle(indexes)
            indexes = indexes[:int(percent*len(indexes))]
            for i in range(len(indexes)):
                indexes[i] = obj+'.vtx['+str(indexes[i])+']'
                brightness = random.uniform(0.1,1.0)
                rgb = (brightness, brightness, brightness)
                cmds.polyColorPerVertex (rgb=rgb)
            vertexes.extend(indexes)
        cmds.select(vertexes, r=1)

get_random_vertexes()
```

Instead of having a noisy range of color values on the mesh it is filled with a flat color. How do I make sure each vert gets assigned a color as it's being selected while not touching other verts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you don't pass anything to `cmds.polyColorPerVertex` so that every time you call it, it colors whatever is currently selected (in this case all verts from the sphere). If you pass a vert though that function it will set it on the single vert as expected:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import random


sphereList = cmds.ls('mySphere*')
if sphereList:  # Can shorten if statement.
    cmds.delete(sphereList)

new_obj, _ = cmds.polySphere (r=50, sx=random.randrange(10, 20), sy=random.randrange(10, 20), name='mySphere#')
cmds.setAttr('{}.displayColors'.format(new_obj), True)  # Display vert colors.

cmds.polyColorSet(new_obj, create=True, colorSet='colorSet1')

def set_random_vertexes(percent=1):  # Move percent as a parameter so it's not hard-coded.
    vertexes = []

    for obj in cmds.ls(sl=1, long=1):
        all_verts = cmds.ls('{}.vtx[*]'.format(obj), flatten=True)  # Use `cmds.ls` with `flatten` to get a list of all vertexes.
        random.shuffle(all_verts)
        verts = all_verts[:int(percent * len(all_verts))]

        for vert in verts:
            brightness = random.uniform(0.1, 1.0)
            rgb = (brightness, brightness, brightness)
            cmds.polyColorPerVertex(vert, rgb=rgb)  # Pass vert's name to change its color.

        vertexes.extend(verts)

    cmds.select(vertexes, r=1)

set_random_vertexes()
```

I also included a few optimizations in there. You might want to consider changing the name of the function `get_random_vertexes` as it feels misleading by setting vertexes instead of returning a list of them.